# What plant is this and is it supposed to be indoor?

Tags: identification, indoors

we have beautiful plant at home, but I suspect that it draws out oxygen from room. Can you help me with identifying this plant and suggest whether it is okay to have it indoor, or whether there is anything special to take care of?

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Zamioculcas zamiifolia, usually known as ZZ plant (for fairly obvious reasons!). It's an easy care houseplant, but your idea that it draws oxygen from a room is incorrect - plants, as a general rule, take in carbon dioxide and emit oxygen, and some plants actually take up indoor pollutants and clean up the air, though this isn't one of them.

Water thoroughly when the surface of the soil in the pot feels dry to the touch, empty out any outer pot or tray 30 minutes later so the plant is not left sitting in water. It will do reasonably well with low light levels, but will grow more slowly than when kept in bright daylight; keep it out of direct sun, and away from heat sources such as radiators. Average room temperatures will be fine. More info here https://www.houseplantsexpert.com/zz-plant.html